# Entropy vs Relative Entropy.

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory, entropy, large-deviation-theory

Can anyone help me reconcile two well known observations.

---

$\textbf{Observation 1}$

The Second Law of Thermodynamics says that a system wants to minimise (the negative of entropy)

$$
H(\rho):=\int \rho \log \rho,
$$

where $\rho$ is a probability density on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

$\textbf{Observation 2}$

If we consider some random variables on $\mathbb{R}^d$, $X_i\sim \mu$ for $i=1,2,\ldots$ with empirical distribution

$$
\rho_n:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{X_i}
$$

then Sanov's Theorem says that $\rho_n$ satisfies

$$
\mathbb{P}(\rho_n\approx \rho) \approx \exp\big(-n H(\rho|\mu)\big),
$$

where

$$
H(\rho|\mu):=\begin{cases}
\int f\log f~&\text{if}~\rho \ll\mu ~\text{and}~\rho=f\mu
\\
\infty~&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
is Relative Entropy against $\mu$.

---

$\textbf{Question}$

Here its typical to think of $\mu$ as the stationary distribution of a stochastic process. Whats the link between these two observations, is the first just a time dependent version of the second?

Comment: As far as I see, these statements are talking about different things, and there's no relation between them. The first statement is saying that if the law of a physical system is evolving, then it will increase in entropy. In equilibirium, this law will be a maximum entropy law subject to the appropriate mean-conversation constraints (this is why you often see Gibbs distributions in stat mech). The second statement is saying that if you draw many samples from a fixed law $\mu$, then their emprical distribution looks like $\mu$ itself (and gives a rate of convergence to $\mu$).

Comment: @stochasticboy321 is observation 2 not a 'equilibrium analogue' of observation 1?

Comment: Check out: From a Large-Deviations Principle to the Wasserstein Gradient Flow: A New Micro-Macro Passage, by Zimmer et.al